# is ultra super saiyan a transformation or a state?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the battle of Vegeta vs Trunks, when Trunks goes ultra super saiyan, Vegeta states: "are you still relying on that sluggish transformation?".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cc1dfGll0ak

That leads me to think ultra super saiyan is indeed a (useless) transformation and not a state, but now in the manga Wiss states Goku has 5 transformations, 1,2,3 god and blue. Since Goku was also able to go Ultra Super Saiyan, what does this mean, is Ultra Super Saiyan a transformation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ultra Super Saiyan transformation, is a forced increase in the power output of the Super Saiyan transformation and is not a new transformation. You could compare it to a Super Saiyan 2 transformation. The only difference would be that the Ultra Saiyan transformation increases muscle mass at the expense of speed.